# Able to click on a button/hyperlink only at the upper half of the text

Tags: html, css

I am not able click on the text/ button if I hover over it at the lower bottom.
I dont know what is causing this problem. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li ng-repeat="crumb in breadcrumbs" ng-class="{ active: $last }"><a
            ui-sref="{{ crumb.route }}" ng-if="!$last"
            ng-mouseover="true"
            translate>{{ crumb.displayName }}&nbsp;</a><span ng-show="$last" translate>{{ crumb.displayName
            }}</span></li>
</ol>
```

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Please, provide sample within css on site like [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @ n4nn31355 https://jsfiddle.net/3a8bbkmq/ here is the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pointer 1**

Put your anchor in a `<li>` tag

```
    <li> <a ui-sref="findeventshome.findevents" translate class="eventsLink">LOGIN_PERSON_OWN_EVENTS</a></li>
```

and style with this

**Pointer 2**

At the lower buttom of your css script you have padding in your bar, that is why your anchor wasn't occuping all the space in your container

this is what you have

```
.panel-heading {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
```

take out the  `padding: 10px 15px;`

style your anchor tag like this

```
  a:active,a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden; 
  display: inline-block;
  width:auto;

        }
  li {
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0;
  margin:none;
   }
```

here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/pypqkfpu/

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Shruthi Sathyanarayana,

Please provide us a link or URL where we can check this issue, its seems that you are enable to click the the button or link completely, for this please check the `line-height`, `padding`, or `display` property in your code.

**CSS**

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

this will help you, please check and try this code.

Comment: @ Kamal Kumar  jsfiddle.net/3a8bbkmq here is my link

Comment: I added  display: block; but it is still not working :(

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana, i have seen your code, you want, the anchor to be fully click-able from the whole panel

Comment: @ShruthiSathyanarayana, please check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/itskamalkumar/1L4Lhabf/

Comment: I think it will help you, if not you can add `padding` to the anchor and remove `padding` from the pannel